# Run rails app on a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

This might seem like a very easy question however I wasn't able to find any resources on the internet.

If you have a server, say `abc.alphabet.com` how would you make that serve your rails app when the user types that url?

I found things such as passenger, nginx however I wasn't able to find anything that guided me step-by-step through the process of uploading your rails app to your server, and making it so that whenever that url is typed my rails app will fire up and do its thing

Again, I appreciate it's a novice question but I wasn't able to find anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you say `abc.alphabet.com` you mean a domain and not a server. Domain is just a like a entry in a dictionary. It means that this url would be associated to a server ip where your rails app has to be running. Now this server would mean like a remote computer where you would have to install a HTTP server like nginx and start your app on it. If you are finding it too difficult there are many websites that provides web hoisting services. You could try them. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) is a great start. Also check  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162144/what-are-the-good-ruby-on-rails-hosting-service-out-there).